# Render a frame on demand

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm currently creating a NTSC signal decoder/simulator, and basically, I'd like to be able to prepare a frame before rendering it, such as, read an array, process data, draw some pixels accordingly, and then render the frame. I've tried getting rid of the `glutMainLoop();` thing, and just using a handmade loop:

```
for(;;) { 
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Whatever I might have to do goes somewhere in here
    glFlush(); 
}
```

This, however, doesn't work, `glClearColor` and `glClear`, probably also `glFlush` get executed, but just one time, after that, the program just hangs, what can I do to avoid this?

Comment: There's usually some sort of SwapBuffers function you have to call after rendering a frame. It's platform specific though, not part of GL itself.

Comment: What function is it hanging on? You've got an infinite loop and you've removed the main event loop, so it's probably not getting update events.

Comment: I can not tell if you are using Legacy OpenGL such as OpenGL 1 which in todays time is considered deprecated or if you are using modern OpenGL at least version 3.3+ up to current 4.6. Regardless of which version you are using; this webpage from this online tutorial for OpenGL gives a very good description of Frame Buffers in OpenGL! https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried getting rid of the `glutMainLoop();` thing, and just using a handmade loop
>   ... after that, the program just hangs ...

This is a bad idea, because in general the only way to get a event handling when using [GLUT](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/spec3.html) is `glutMainLoop()`.

See [`glutMainLoop`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node14.html#SECTION00041000000000000000):

> `glutMainLoop` enters the GLUT event processing loop. This routine should be called at most once in a GLUT program. Once called, this routine will never return. It will call as necessary any callbacks that have been registered.

Note, `glutMainLoop()` doesn't only call the call back function which you have set by `glutDisplayFunc`, it also receives and processes the IO events like mouse and keyboard events. If you don't use the `glutMainLoop()`, then you have no event handling and of course no IO event handling. This causes that the program seems to hang and doesn't react on any input.
Either you have to use `glutMainLoop()` or you have to switch a other window API like [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/), where you can explicitly activate the event processing by [`glfwPollEvents()`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga37bd57223967b4211d60ca1a0bf3c832)

Newer implementations of GLUT, like [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php) provide some additional functionality. `glutMainLoopEvent()` does the same as `glutMainLoop()`, but it does it only once. It does a single iteration of the event loop and gives control back immediately. So you can implement your own loop handles your application.

e.g.

```
void display( void )
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Whatever I might have to do goes somewhere in here
    glFlush();
}

int main()
{
    .....

    glutDisplayFunc(display);  

    .....

    for(;;)
    {
        glutMainLoopEvent(); // handle the main loop once
        glutPostRedisplay(); // cause `display` to be called in `glutMainLoopEvent`
    }

    .....
}
```

It is even possible to set a *dummy* display function, which does nothing, and do the drawing in the loop:

e.g.

```
void dummyDisplay( void )
{
    // does nothing
}

int main()
{
    .....

    glutDisplayFunc(dummyDisplay);  

    .....

    for(;;)
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Whatever I might have to do goes somewhere in here
        glFlush();

        glutMainLoopEvent(); // does the event handling once
    }

    .....
}
```